# AWS Chatbot and EventBridge for Glue Job State Changes Error - Event received is not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-event-bridge, aws-chatbot

I am trying to set up the AWS Chatbot with Slack integrations to display error messages for changes in states (errors) for AWS Glue. I have set up AWS EventBridge event pattern to catch Glue Job State Changes as follows:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.glue"],
  "detail-type": ["Glue Job State Change"],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "FAILED"
    ]
  }
}
```

This successfully catches all failed Glue Jobs and I have set up an AWS SNS topic as the target using the input transformer.

**Input Transformer Input Path**

```
{"jobname":"$.detail.jobName","jobrunid":"$.detail.jobRunId","jobstate":"$.detail.state"}
```

**Input Transformer Input Template**

```
"{\"detail-type\": \"Glue Job <job-name> has entered the state <job-state> with the message <message>.\"}"
```

AWS SNS has a subscriptions endpoint to the AWS Chatbot which fails to send the notification to Slack.

**AWS Chatbot CloudWatch logs after an event using Input Transformer**

```
Event received is not supported (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chatbot/latest/adminguide/related-services.html ): 
{
    "subscribeUrl": null,
    "type": "Notification",
    "signatureVersion": "1",
    "signature": <signature>,
    "topicArn": <topic-arn>,
    "signingCertUrl": <signing-cert-url>,
    "messageId": <message-id>,
    "message": "{\"detail-type\": \"Glue Job MyJob has entered the state FAILED with the message SystemExit: None.\"}",
    "subject": null,
    "unsubscribeUrl": <unsubscribe-url>,
    "timestamp": "2022-03-02T12:17:16.879Z",
    "token": null
}
```

When the input is set to 'Matched Events' in the AWS EventBridge Select Target, the Slack Notification will send however it lacks any details.

**Slack Notification**

```
Glue Job State Change | eu-west-1 | Account: <account>
Glue Job State Change
```

**AWS EventBridge Matched Events JSON Output**

```
{
    "Type" : "Notification",
    "MessageId" : <message-id>,
    "TopicArn" : <topic-arn>,
    "Message" : "{\"detail-type\": [\"Glue Job State Change\"]}",
    "Timestamp" : "2022-03-02T11:17:52.443Z",
    "SignatureVersion" : "1",
    "Signature" : <signature>,
    "SigningCertURL" : <signing-cert-url>,
    "UnsubscribeURL" : <unsubscribe-url>
  }
```

There are very little differences between the two JSON outputs however the input transformer is considered an unsupported event. Is it possible to generate a custom message when using the AWS Chatbot for errors?

Comment: Looks like there are limitations of the AWS Chatbot listed in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854288/can-i-customize-messages-received-through-slacks-aws-chatbot-integration

Answer (score 0):

The best solution was to create a Lambda function as the target of the AWS EventBridge which performs a POST to a [Slack Webhook](https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/articles/115005265063-Incoming-webhooks-for-Slack).

```
# Import modules
import logging
import json
import urllib3

# Set up logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


# Define Lambda function
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    
    url = <url>
    link = <glue-studio-monitoring-link>
    message = f"A Glue Job {event['detail']['jobName']} with Job Run ID {event['detail']['jobRunId']} has entered the state {event['detail']['state']} with error message: {event['detail']['message']}. Visit the link for job monitoring {link}"
    logger.info(message)
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
    data = {'text': message}
    response = http.request('POST',
                        url,
                        body = json.dumps(data),
                        headers = headers,
                        retries = False)
    logger.info(response.status)
```